# Table with ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, tabular

I'm trying to build a table using ng-repeat but I also want to use a toolbar. The table should look something like this but for example under "After the civil war" I need to add three more rows.

[image]

```
<md-grid-tile><h4>Radiographic Feature Type</h4></md-grid-tile>
        <md-grid-tile><h4>You: Mean % Missed Feature</h4></md-grid-tile>
        <md-grid-tile><h4>ALL PARTICIPANTS: % Missed Feature</h4></md-grid-tile>


        <md-grid-tile>




        </md-grid-tile>


        <md-grid-tile ng-repeat-start="thisCase in caselist | limitTo : 5">


        </md-grid-tile>


        <md-grid-tile ng-repeat-end="">


        </md-grid-tile>


    </md-grid-list>
```

All the help is much appreciated and I'm sorry but I just started coding and I haven't got much experience.

Answer (score 0):

That`s how it should looks like according to official docs

```
       <ul class="phones">
          <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
            <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
            <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

try to change li tag to yours md-grid-tite and you should add {{}} to keep content there

here is great tutorial
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_01